# what is the meaning of $\theta$ in normed space?

Tags: functional-analysis

I was reading this [book](https://bookstore.ams.org/coll-31)

**Theorem $2.5.1$** :If a  subadditive functional $F(x)$ defined on normed linear space $X$ is non-negative  outside of a sphere , then it is non -negative for all $x \in X$

**Proof**:

suppose $F(x) \ge 0 $   for all $x$  , $||x|| \ge R$ .Then for a  given $x$ , $||x|| <R$, there is positive

integer $n $ with $n||x|| \ge R$ $\color{blue}{unless , of course , x= \theta}$. Hence $0 \le F(nx) \le n F(x) $ and

$F(x) \ge 0$.For $x= \theta$ we have $F(\theta) \le 2F(\theta)$ so that $F(\theta) \ge 0$

**My doubts** : Im not getting the  meaning of $\theta$ and also im not getting the sentence that given in blue colour

Comment: It is probably the null vector of the linear space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some presentations for beginners do this.  You may think that using the same symbol "$0$" for both the zero scalar and the zero vector is confusing.  So use another symbol "$\theta$" for the zero vector.

Of course, this would be a very bad book if the symbol $\theta$ is used this way without previously being defined!